# How to convert a string to XML

Tags: xml, go

I have an XML in string format, can someone help me in convert the XML string to proper XML format?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    message := `<?xml proflie ><test> value '123'</test>`
    fmt.Printf("%s", message)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `encoding/xml` package with the `EscapeText` function:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

func Xml(in string) string {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    xml.EscapeText(&b, []byte(in))
    return b.String()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(`<?xml profile><test>` + Xml(`test '123'`) + `</test>`)
}
```

This will produce output: `test &#39;123&#39;`

Go has excellent support for XML in the `encoding/xml` package, and there are other ways to produce your output that don't involve manually constructing your XML.

This version does the wrapping in the `<test>` element, and also allows you to pass an `interface{}` to the `EncodeElement` method, so you're not limited to strings:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    s := `test '123'`
    test := xml.StartElement{Name:xml.Name{Local:`test`}}
    xml.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).EncodeElement(s, test)
}
```

Finally, and probably best of all, this version uses a `stuct` and the `.Encode` method:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "os"
)

type Test struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"test"`
    Content string `xml:",chardata"`
}
func main() {
    s := Test{Content:`test '123'`}
    xml.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(&s)
}
```

Now you can extend the struct, but best of all, you can also `Unmarshal` or `Decode` this type, to extract data from incoming XML:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Test struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"test"`
    Content string `xml:",chardata"`
}

func main() {
    s := Test{Content:`test '123'`}
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    xml.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(&s)
    fmt.Println("Encoded =", buf.String())

    var read Test
    xml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes())).Decode(&read)
    fmt.Println("Content =", read.Content)
}
```

See the documentation on `xml.Marshal` for a full description of the tags supported by the xml package: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. Let me brief my query. I have to read the XML file which was already present in the mongo db, and the same i am able to read in string. So without hanging the anything to that string i would like to print the string to XML format wihtout using any struct. Can you help me with that please.

Comment: Use the `function Xml(string) string` in the very first example to make a particular string XML safe.

Comment: How to get ride of special characters from the output? test &#39;123&#39;

Comment: You _want_ those special characters - that's the XML encoding! Otherwise, you're _decoding_. See `xml.Unmarshal` or `xml.Decoder`.